# Pass click variable to function within function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When a link is clicked I want the hash info passed into a child function.  Please see below.  Right now when I click on a link the URL says /#undefined.

```
 $j(window.location.hash).collapse('show');
 $j('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function() {
     $j('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
         window.location.hash = $j(this).attr('href');
     });
 });
```

Comment: You're sure you don't want `window.location.hash = this.id;`

Comment: Also note that `this` inside the callback for the collapse, probably isn't the clicked element, unless you have an anchor with the class `collapse` and that data attribute ?

Comment: @adeno  YOU SIR ARE THE MAN (OR WOMAN)!!!!

Comment: Uhm, you're welcome, I think? I'm guessing you figured it out

Comment: I did. your suggestion of window.location.hash = this.id; worked like a charm.

Comment: There you go. I just noticed you were doing `$j(window.location.hash)`, and the logical opposite would be `window.location.hash = this.id;`, so I guessed wildly

Answer (score 0):

Pass it along, like so:

```
$j(window.location.hash).collapse('show');
$j('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function () {
    var href = $j(this).attr('href');
    $j('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (href) {
        window.location.hash = href;           
    });
});
```